# Punctuation marks

Tags: punctuation

I have the following sentence:

> Please first look at our wiki space or contact your local siteops before opening a ticket, if you would like us to look into an issue, or have a change request, please open a JIRA ticket.

I was told I have grammar mistakes, especially with punctuation marks. Could someone please tell me how to make it better?

Comment: Replace the comma after *ticket* with a semicolon—or use a period and start a second sentence.

Comment: As stated, your sentence is ambiguous, or, at the least, a "garden path" construction.  You need to make clear which end of your "sentence" is qualified by the "if" clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence:

> Please first look at our wiki space or contact your local site-ops before opening a ticket, if you would like us to look into an issue, or have a change request, please open a JIRA ticket.

As it is, your sentence is both a comma splice and a run-on sentence. Let's punctuate it a little better. That involves changing a run-on sentence into two separate sentences.

> Before opening a ticket, please look first at our wiki space or contact your local site-ops. If you would like us to look into an issue, or you would like to submit [better word than *have*?] a change request, please open a JIRA ticket.

There are other--and perhaps preferable--ways to punctuate your instructions, but my suggestion is perhaps as good as any.

Comment: The original is more than just a run-on sentence. It's an example of a comma splice (two independent clauses joined by a comma without a conjunction). While some comma splices are acceptable stylistically, I can't imagine anyone thinking this one is. For it to be *just* a run-on sentence, add *and* before the *if*.

Comment: Gotcha, Jason. Thanks. I cannot change my answer (I guess) after the OP's question is kaput. Don

Comment: You should certainly be able to edit your sentence if you wish; when I click *edit*, it shows me an edit window, and it shouldn't be any different for you as the author. (Perhaps an edit to say "your sentence is both a comma splice and a run-on sentence"—assuming you want to make any change at all.)

Comment: @JasonBassford: Thanks, Jason. Perhaps I was not logged in when I tried to make some changes. Don